# Do static generators maintain a constant voltage at the terminals?

Tags: voltage, generator, solar-energy, power-grid, static

Do static generators maintain the terminal voltage constant like a synchronous generator does? If not, are they at constant current? With static generator I mean photovoltaic systems connected to the AC grid through inverter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid-tied inverters will always attempt to match the grid voltage and frequency.  As the grid goes up and down in voltage, so will the inverter.

Assuming constant insolation, a photovoltaic system will act approximately as a constant power source.  The inverter will pull as much power as it can from the solar panels, and push that out to the grid at whatever the grid voltage is at that moment.

In reality, constant insolation isn't going to be true over a period of hours, and the inverter will always output as much power as it can.